# How to use Intent In ListView

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android Program I take a List of some application name like

1.Task Reminder     2.Profile

Now I want to click this list and want to enter into this application. I already write class for both of of the program. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this by using Intent?

Comment: are you interested to call an activity from an intent?

Comment: Ya I want to call an activity from an intent but from different package

Comment: the below answers will help you solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Use this to add listeners to your listview

```
yourListViwObject.OnItemClickListener(this);
```

and when you use this your class will be prompted to implement OnItemClickListener .Do that and your class will ask you to add unimplemented methods .When you add them you will get a method onItemClick() and implement what you need to implement in this method like below

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

   Toast.makeText(this,
    "Item is clicked " + arg2,
    600).show();
   Intent i = new Intent(YourClass.this, TheActivityYouNeedToInvoke.class);
   startActivity(i);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
            View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
            {
                Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), profile.class);
                // you can pass the value to profile class using "n.putExtra(name, value);"
                startActivity(n);
            }

        });
```